# Installing and running both 32 bit and 64 bit python at the same time -module issues

Tags: python, installation, module, 64-bit, 32-bit

I have one module that only runs on 32 bit python.  I then have subprocesses that need to launch on 64 bit python for memory reasons.  There are also about 8 modules that I need to use.  I installed everything and actually had both the 32 bit and 64 bit versions running at the same time.  But then had to install one more module 'datetime'.  After I installed that it went back to this issue. I tried uninstalling 'datetime' and that did not fix.

OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application

So I followed advice to do what originally seemed to allow both to run by using pip install -- pywin32==227

That said it was already satisfied so I tried
pip install -- pywin32==228 then back to pip install -- pywin32==227

Still this error
OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application

I noticed that despite having two versions of python (32 and 64 bit) in two different folders it is storing all modules in \AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages and I am wondering how it distinguishes between a 32 bit module install and a 64 bit.

The most frustrating thing about this issue is for one brief moment, I actually had both running so I know it is possible, but not sure how at this point.  Is there a recommended way to have two (32 and 64) bit pythons running at the same time with two unique sets of modules installed?  At this point, I would start over with all of the installations as needed.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that python uses the same location for site.getusersitepackages() for 32-bit and 64-bit versions of python.

It appears that your installation process for your modules is using usersitepackages because you specified the directory causing you problems was \AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages which is usersitepackages which appears earlier than the regular site-packages in sys.path (but only if the directory exists - hence not everybody knows about usersitepackages).

This seems to be a bug with the Python release - it has annoyed me as well since I prefer to install my extensions in usersitepackages since I may not have write access to the regular site-packages directory.

You can fix it as follows:

Edit the file Lib/site.py in your Python package (of course you might not have write access - see above).

There is a function called _get_path in this file which looks a bit like this:

```
def _get_path(userbase):
    version = sys.version_info
    if os.name == 'nt':
        return f'{userbase}\\Python{version[0]}{version[1]}\\site-packages'
```

So very good - it gets the right version of Python - but does nothing about the number of bits. Since we are recoding this function you should do this:

```
return f'{userbase}\\Python{version[0]}{version[1]}-32\\site-packages'
```

or this:

```
return f'{userbase}\\Python{version[0]}{version[1]}-64\\site-packages'
```

depending on whether you are editing the 32-bit version or the 64-bit version.

I suppose you could find out the architecture if you wanted to be pure and logical
(in order to have the same implementation of site.py for all releases).

e.g.

```
import platform
platform.architecture()[0]
```

should return 32bit or 64bit - so this is what I think the Python development team should do if they read this comment.